# Cannot resolve class for Hibernate4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nhibernate-4

I'm actually trying to import an external dao and an external persistence in a new Spring Boot application. I never do that before, and pursuant to another developper explanations, I've created:

ApplicationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    
    <import resource="classpath:/daos.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:/spring-datasource-config.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:/spring-hibernate-config.xml" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer"/>
</beans>
```

then a Spring-hibernate-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>mapping/JItem.xml</value>
             </list>
        </property>

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
```

The problem is that it cannot find "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"

Did I forget something?

EDIT: I tried to force hibernate 4 in pom.xml (adding a property and declare the hibernate dependency at the end):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.4.final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

but it doesn't solve the problem and I still have the "cannot resolve class or package hibernate4" in the config xml....

I absolutely don't know how to solve this...

Comment: The version of Spring (Boot) you are using doesn't support HIbernate 4 anymore, only hibernate 5 and higher.

Comment: oh, ok perfect. Do you know versionI can use for it?